# How can I apply to extend my tourist visa for Schengen area (to stay in Belgium)?

Tags: schengen

I'm with a special situation as I came to Belgium with a tourist visa to then here apply for a Work Permit type B, but my employer didn't go through with the demand and now I have +/- 2 weeks left with a possibility to get a new employer, but I would need to extend my visa as the permit process takes time.

I'd like to know how and where can I apply for a new tourist visa please?

Answer (score 2):

Normally you must apply for a *tourist* visa from your place of residence, outside the Schengen area. There are some cases when you can apply for a work visa from within Belgium. [Do any of these apply to you?](https://dofi.ibz.be/sites/dvzoe/EN/Application-guides/Pages/Employees_stay.aspx) It also differs for employees and self-employed workers, you mentioned that you plan to become an employee.